# Does Visual Studio include a search & replace that keeps the 'wildcard' value?

Tags: visual-studio

I converted a ASP.NET 4.5 application to .NET Core 3.0
It is all running smoothly but now I want to add Localization to the models, I have localized all views but the models look like they do not need a lot of handwork because every Model Property already has a `[DisplayName("Name")]` on it, but I want to get this from the resource file, so by hand I would need to change this to `[Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType  = typeof(MyResources))]`

I was wondering if there is a Find and replace functionality that replaces `DisplayName` with `Display(Name=` and than keeps the value after the `name=` and than adds `, ResourceType  = typeof(MyResources))` to the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Find and Replace dialog enable **Use Regular Expressions** and set:

```
Find what = \[DisplayName\("(\w+)"\)\]
Replace with = [Display(Name = "$1", ResourceType = typeof(MyResources))]
```

Comment: Insane! i did not know I can use regular expressions like that!